# React Native Maps only shows one marker

Tags: react-native

I have tried a few things and looked a few examples and still, I can only get one marker to show. If I test on Android & iOS I get the same thing. Only one marker is showing. I followed a few YouTube channels and copy them exactly, still I see no difference. Here is what I have. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
const markers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    coordinate: {
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
    },
    image: images.userMarker,
    title: 'Samantha',
    description: 'User location'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    coordinate: {
      latitude: 37.98825,
      longitude: -126.4324,
    },
    image: images.shieldMarker,
    title: 'Shield',
    description: 'Shield location'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    coordinate: {
      latitude: 4.78825,
      longitude: -120.4324,
    },
    image: images.dogMarker,
    title: 'Snopp Doggy Dog',
    description: 'Dog location'
  },
]
```

```
<MapView
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsCompass={true}
        loadingEnabled = {true}
        loadingIndicatorColor="#666666"
        loadingBackgroundColor="#eeeeee"
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        ref={_map}
        initialRegion={region}
        style={styles.map}
      >
        {
          markers.map((marker, index) => {
            return (
              <Marker
                key={index}
                coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                title={marker.title}
                description={marker.description}
              >
                <Image
                  source={marker.image}
                  style={{
                    height: globals.SCREEN_SIZE.width * 0.17,
                    width: globals.SCREEN_SIZE.width * 0.15,
                  }}
                />
              </Marker>
            )
          })
        }

      </MapView>
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly, but the coordinates you chose are way too far apart from each other at your zoom level to see on screen.

Keep zooming out and you will see your other 2 markers

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can fit the markers on the coords

try to use this:

```
useEffect(() => {
      mapRef?.current?.fitToCoordinates(markers, {
        edgePadding: { top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50, right: 50 },
        animated: true,
      });
    
  }, [markers]);
```

This should fit all the markers on map.